# Where is Qiskit's RepetitionCode class now?

Tags: qiskit, python

Now that Qiskit's `ignis` module has been deprecated, where does `qiskit.ignis.verification.topological_codes.RepetitionCode` or its equivalent reside now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [migration guide](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis#migration-guide):

> `topological_codes` will continue development under [NCCR-SPIN](https://github.com/NCCR-SPIN/topological_codes/blob/master/README.md), while the functionality is reintegrated into Qiskit. Some additional functionality can also be found in the offshoot project [qtcodes](https://github.com/yaleqc/qtcodes).

Looking at the NCCR-SPIN repository, we can see that [the `RepetitionCode` is indeed defined there](https://github.com/NCCR-SPIN/topological_codes/blob/d613ea12a72a1fa077d4ebdd13d4e4dc47494f99/topological_codes/circuits.py#L23):

```
class RepetitionCode:
    """
    Implementation of a distance d repetition code, implemented over
    T syndrome measurement rounds.
    """

    def __init__(self, d, T=0, xbasis=False, resets=False, delay=0, barriers=False):
        """
        Creates the circuits corresponding to a logical 0 and 1 encoded
        using a repetition code.
        Args:
            d (int): Number of code qubits (and hence repetitions) used.
            T (int): Number of rounds of ancilla-assisted syndrome measurement.
            xbasis (bool): Whether to use the X basis to use for encoding (Z basis used by default).
            resets (bool): Whether to include a reset gate after mid-circuit measurements.
            delay (float): Time (in dt) to delay after mid-circuit measurements (and delay).
            barrier (bool): Boolean denoting whether to include a barrier at the end.
        Additional information:
            No measurements are added to the circuit if `T=0`. Otherwise
            `T` rounds are added, followed by measurement of the code
            qubits (corresponding to a logical measurement and final
            syndrome measurement round).
        """
```